# Issue with implementing inverse FFT for polynoms

Tags: python, algorithm, fft

I am studying the FFT algorithm for fast polynomial multiplication. We went over the algorithm and I decided to try and implement it in Python.

```py
from typing import List
import numpy as np


def fft(p: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    n = len(p)
    if n == 1:
        return p
    
    unity_root = np.exp(2j * np.pi / n)
    
    p_even = p[::2]
    p_odd = p[1::2]
    
    y_even = fft(p_even)
    y_odd = fft(p_odd)
    
    y = [0] * n
    for j in range(n // 2):
        omega = np.power(unity_root, j)
        y[j] = y_even[j] + omega * y_odd[j]
        y[n // 2 + j] = y_even[j] - omega * y_odd[j]
    
    return y


def ifft(p: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    n = len(p)
    if n == 1:
        return p
    
    unity_root = (1 / n) * np.exp(-2j * np.pi / n)
    
    p_even = p[::2]
    p_odd = p[1::2]
    
    y_even = ifft(p_even)
    y_odd = ifft(p_odd)
    
    y = [0] * n
    for j in range(n // 2):
        omega = np.power(unity_root, j)
        y[j] = y_even[j] + omega * y_odd[j]
        y[n // 2 + j] = y_even[j] - omega * y_odd[j]
    
    return y
```

I tried running the following code to make sure it works

```py
print(ifft(fft([1, 2, 3, 4])))
```

I expected the output to be the original list I started with as that list represents the coefficients, yet I am getting (ignoring precision issues with floating point arithmetic):

```
[(4+0j), (11-0j), (12+0j), (13+0j)]
```

My question is:

Shouldn't I be getting the original list? If I should be getting the original list, where is the mistake in the code? as I went over the code several times and I am having issues finding it. If I shouldn't be getting the original list back and my code is correct, what am I actually getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in `ifft`, you're dividing the root of unity by `n`. You need to divide the final result instead.

Comment: A note: divide the final result, but not in the recursive function, only at the very end.

Comment: This solution seems to work wonders! I also now noticed that in the original IFFT matrix we multiply by the 1/n after multiply the wondermonde matrix by the vector, so your solution also makes sense to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another issue : `fft` is performing inverse fft, and `ifft` is performing fft ..